# Configure AWS SQS Dead Letter Queue in AWS for a specific error message

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, dead-letter, dlq

Is there any way in `AWS SQS` to route only the messages failed with particular error message to `DLQ` (Dead Letter Queue)?

By default, all the unprocessed messages are sent to `DLQ`. Is there any way to customize it based on error message?

Comment: No, but you might be able to stop some 'failed' messages being sent to the Dead Letter Queue by returning a 'success' code instead of an error code. Why are your messages generally failing?

Comment: If the consumer of the source queue fails to process a message a specified number of times defined as `maxReceiveCount` then only the message is moved to the dead-letter queue. That might be one of the reason other than error while processing the message. Kindly investigate to see what is the actual reason refer https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-dead-letter-queues.html form more info

Comment: Basically when the error is known, I do not want the SQS to retry the same message repeatedly.

Comment: @KingstonX If that is the requirement you have to handle the exception and return the `success code` as @JohnRotenstein is telling, you can also try to look to identify and move the message to `DLQ` using code or just look for `RedrivePolicy`